# What is the equivalent of an apache module in java server technology

Tags: java, asp.net, apache, iis

I have a task to examine incoming HTTP requests and do some processing on the header and request body then store that locally.

If I understand correctly, I can do that with an [apache module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) for Apache servers and an [IIS extension](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework) for IIS. I'm not clear on what I would use for Java based application servers.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In which server do you have to accomplish the task, .Net server (IIS or another) or Java (Tomcat, JBoss, etc)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I have to do it for a few application servers including java based. Right now we're thinking of starting with Tomcat but I'd want an approach that could work across as many Java platforms as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use a Java application server, then you should handle this in a Servlet Filter. Here's an example:

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //Set init params and load any resources to be used in this class.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Here you will pre and post process the request-response cycle.
        //Pre process is before executing "chain.doFilter(req, res);"
        //Post process is after executing "chain.doFilter(req, res);"
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

        String someRequestHeader = request.getHeader("<header-you-want-or-need>");
        //do what you need to do
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //Close/free any resources used in this class.
    }

}
```

More info:

- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial. 17 Java Servlet Technology. 17.6 Filtering Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets006.htm#BNAGB)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Also have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm#BNAFD).

Comment: If it is a Java application server, the best place would be a Servlet Filter rather than a Servlet.